# Is there React Component event when User looking at the component? (ex. post)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Is there a React event that triggers when user is looking at the component? 
Like ComponentEnteredShowArea

Examples are like facebook post videos automatically play when I'm looking at it.

It would be nice if it has nothing to do with scroll.

Comment: `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` will be triggered right before and after component is mounted on DOM.

Comment: What I wanted is to fetch posts as a card and send back 'viewed' message back to server when It's views by user.
If I use componentWillMount or componentDidMount, It could send 'viewed' message to server even when user didn't saw it.

Comment: No there is no such lifecycle method. But you can use simple javascript to achieve that.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an event listener for window scrolling in componentDidMount then use vanilla javascript or React refs to determine if specific elements have come into view.

https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/